# Shape (preferably human) recognition API for use with standard webcam

Tags: api, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

I am interested in getting into user interaction/shape detection with a simple usb webcam. I can use multiple webcams, but don't want to be restricted to using something like the kinect sensor. My detection cameras need to be set up on either side of a helmet (or if an individual one, on top). I have found some, but they don't really have the functionality I need and most are angled towards facial recognition. I need to be able to detect a basic human skeletal structure and determine if something is obstructing it. I would really rather be able to do it without using any sort of marker system on the target person. I would like for it to be able to target multiple structures. Obviously I am willing to do tweaking if necessary, but want to see how close I can get to what I need before I rebuild the wheel. I am trying to design an ai system that can determine how many people are in an area and where they are.

Answer (score 0):

Doubt there will be anything like this since Microsoft spent a ton of money on the R&D for Kinect and it's probably all locked behind an NDA. I'm also guessing there's a lot of hardware within the Kinect that is not available in a standard webcam.

The closest thing that I could find to what you're looking for is the [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) project, might be a good place to start your research.